# Copying files to usr/local in Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, filesystem, permissions, root

I have been trying to install Opencv following the instructions given in this link [https://github.com/manashmndl/FabLabRpiWorkshop2017/wiki/Painless-OpenCV-in-Raspbian-Stretch]

I need to copy files from `/home/pi/CompiledOpenCV/usr/local` to `/usr/local`
but have no permission to do so.

How can I change permission of the folders or copy files using command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never change permissions on system directories like `/usr/local`. For copying you can use the `sudo` command and maybe you have to make the copied files executable with `chmod` and/or add the user to a proper group with `sudo adduser $USER $GROUP`. And I think your executable should be copied to `/usr/local/bin`. But in general I don't understand why do you take so much effort to compile `OpenCV` from source and install all by hand. You can simply install the libraries from default repositories with e.g.:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install libopencv-video2.4v5
```

or what else library you need. Look with

```
rpi ~$ apt list *opencv*
```